# Error in php login Form Using prepared Statement

Tags: php

I am new to programming Here i am creating simple registration and login form,My registration form works right it register the input given by user in the database properly,But when i use the same username and password in my login form it doesn't work,It doesn't login the user,I am using prepared statement,Any help would be appreciated,Forgive me if i had made some obvious mistake.I look up several tutorials but can't figure it out....

Thanks....

This is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="register.php">
        <div class="container">
            <label>Username :</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br><br>
            <label>Password :</label>
            <input type="Password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
            <button type="sumbit" value="sumbit" name="sumbit">Register</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <form method="POST" action="login.php">
        <div class="container">
            <label>Username :</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br><br>
            <label>Password :</label>
            <input type="Password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
            <button type="sumbit" value="sumbit" name="login">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is my code for login:

```
<?php
include "register.php";

session_start();


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];



$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username ='$username' && password='$password'";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':username',$username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username,$password);
$stmt->store_result();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($stmt->row ==1){

    $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
    header("location: home.php");

}else{
    echo "Username and password is incorrect";

}

?>
```

Comment: You need to use placeholders in the query instead of variables. You also need to hash your password

Comment: You also mix MySQLi and PDO methods

Comment: show some example code it would be a great help for me

Comment: Please show how you are defining `$conn`

Comment: <?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '12345db';
$dbname = 'login';

try{
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=login",$user,$password);
 echo "Connected";

 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}catch(PDOException $e){
 echo "Connection error".$e->getMessage();
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You are binding parameters and the parameters are not in the query string.

Change

```
SELECT * FROM users where username ='$username' && password='$password'
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM users where username =:username && password=:password
```

Answer (score 0):

You mistaken in your sql query and mixed methods of mysqli

```
    <?php
include "register.php";
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username =':username' && password=':password'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); $stmt->bindParam(':username',$username); $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password); $stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($row){
    $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
    header("location: home.php");
}else{
    echo "Username and password is incorrect";
} ?>
```

That's it.

Comment: $stmt-&gt;bind_result($username,$password); $stmt-&gt;store_result();



Remove this two lines from your code

Comment: If (!$_SESSION){
    session_start()
}

Comment: thanks man it helped but in the above code  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username =':username' && password=':password' "; instead of  ':username' ':password ' it should be :username :password without quotation symbol.

Comment: Yeah that why only i am posting it from cell phone so its little bit hard for me&#128514; i hope you can understand